# How to generate .ipa file for React Native app that will communicate to a server-side database configuration like MongoDb?

Tags: ios, react-native, itunes-store

Im newbie to React Native. I am trying to create a native react ios application.

However, if I need to build and ciruculate the app the database will most probably be a db such as MongoDb on a server.

My question is - How do I build the react native app to include server-side database credentials and connection URLs so that the ios application generated can be deployed on any mobile app using itunes to test?

I did look at the documentation available at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/. However, for a newbie this documentation is a little complex from where I am at. If someone could give me enough explanations on how to get this done - would be very grateful.

Comment: You want to connect directly to a mongoDb server? I would Advice you to your a local database like SQLlite or realm. That way you store the information on the phone it self. To update you will make use of a API. That way your app can work offline.

Comment: @Perry Thanks for the response. My app is working fine with local database. Now the thing is I want to submit this app to iTunes App Store. But I don't know how to link the remort database with the app. In meteorjs I used to fire "meteor run ios-device --mobile-server ip:port" command, which open in the xCode. Likewise how can I work with React Native?